# Prove existence of subsequence in finite sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

> $(a)$Let us consider two sequences $a =( a_1,...,a_n)$ and $b =( b_1,...,b_n)$ of distinct real numbers. Show that indices $i_1,...,i_k,1≤ i_1 < ···< i_k ≤ n$, always exist with $k = \Big\lceil n^\frac{1}{4}\Big\rceil$ such that the subsequences determined by them in both $a$ and $b$ are monotone.
>
> $(b)$ Show that the bound for $k$ in $(a)$ cannot be improved in general.

**My attempts**

I think Erdos-Szekeres theorem would help, but I don't see how, since we don't know the factors of $n$. Pigeonhole principle also seems not to do.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The factors of $n$ do not matter.  Just show that there is a monotone sequence in $a_n$ of length $\lceil \sqrt n \rceil$ using the theorem. Then select that subsequence of the $b$s and do the same.

Comment: Thank You, and for the $(b)$ part, I think using the fact that the Erdos-Szekeres theorem doesn't hold for sequence with $n^2$ terms will do?

Comment: You have a sequence of length $\sqrt n$ and want to find a subsequence of length $\sqrt{\sqrt{n}}$.  The theorem applies.